# What is the equivalent cipher to bouncycastle's PaddedBufferedBlockCipher with AESEngine and PKCS7 padding?

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle

I want to decrypt AES-256 encrypted string using nodejs. I am using crypto module for that.

The string is encrypted using Bouncy castle java library. In Java the cipher is intialsed using:

`PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new AESEngine(), new PKCS7Padding());`

[`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.htm) module of nodejs uses openssl's list of ciphers for intialising it, like:

`var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc',key);`

Which algorithm should I use?

Here is the list of algorithms to choose from:

`-bash-4.1$ openssl list-cipher-algorithms|grep AES-256
AES-256-CBC
AES-256-CFB
AES-256-CFB1
AES-256-CFB8
AES-256-CTR
AES-256-ECB
AES-256-OFB
AES-256-XTS
AES256 => AES-256-CBC
aes256 => AES-256-CBC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encrypt something with a block cipher, you need

- the block cipher which can take a single block of input and mangle it into a single block of output (for AES the block size is 16 bytes),
- the mode of operation which enables you to encrypt more than one block in a structured fashion
- the padding which enables you to encrypt something that is not exactly as long as a multiple of the block size.

The `PaddedBufferedBlockCipher` that you've shown only has two of them. The mode of operation is implied to be ECB mode, because it simply consists of applying the block cipher to each block separately.

You'll get the same behavior in node.js with:

```
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-xxx-ecb', key, '');
```

Exchange the `xxx` for the size of your key in bits. Valid sizes are 128 bit, 192 bit and 256 bit. Everything else will not work. Also, make sure that you get the encoding of your key right.

In case you're wondering why `createDecipheriv` is used here instead of `createDecipher`, I suggest that you carefully compare the documentation to both of those functions. `createDecipher` expects a password and not a key.

---

Other considerations:

**Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I solved it the same way after finding that ECB does not take any IV and the `createDecipher(algorithm,password)` creates its own key based on the password.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypt the data with `AES-256-ECB` (I don't see any CBC or other modes.).

Call `decipher.setAutoPadding(true)` for using PKCS padding.